# What do you actually mean by DC voltage gain and AC voltage gain?

Tags: terminology, voltage

What do you actually mean by [DC voltage gain](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=dc+voltage+gain) and [AC voltage gain](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=ac+voltage+gain)? I know their formulas but I do not understand what they actually are? That is, I do not understand their significance is and for what they stand for.  So basically please help me understand what DC voltage gain and AC voltage gain actually are, not just their definition.

Answer (score 2):

"Gain" means how much bigger is the voltage (or current, or power) at the output than at the input.

Gain is important because it allows us to take a small signal and amplify it to make a larger signal. You might want this because, for example, a larger signal will be easier to detect with a analog-to-digital converter, or it might be able to be detected at a farther distance when broadcast as a radio signal.

Answer (score 1):

DC voltage gain (also called steady-state voltage gain) is the ratio: \$\frac{output\:voltage}{input\:voltage}\$ for a direct voltage input. AC voltage gain is the same formula, but for unbiased sinusoidal input and output voltages.