# DC voltage gain vs AC voltage gain, are those the same?

Tags: voltage, transistors, bjt, gain

Is the DC voltage gain the same as the AC voltage gain un a multistage amplifier? I mean, if the last stage have Vo2 as the input and Vo3 as the outout and Vo3/Vo2=1V/V is it correct to say that that's the AC gain?

Comment: The DC gain may be the same, it may be higher, lower, or it may be zero. It'll all depend on the design, and is not a generalizable statement.

Comment: Most multistage amplifiers I've seen have DC gain of zero, as they're capacitively coupled.

Comment: Not entirely a duplicate but asking basically the same thing: [What do you actually mean by DC voltage gain and AC voltage gain?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203174/what-do-you-actually-mean-by-dc-voltage-gain-and-ac-voltage-gain)

Comment: "The gain" is a function of frequency, so a sweep from 0Hz to the max frequency of interest will show the gain and phase response of the amplifier.  "AC gain" only makes sense if you specify a frequency as well.

Comment: Do you expect an answer without showing a circuit diagram with all the frequency dependent parts ?

Comment: Ratio of gains is by design. May be identicalish. May not.